# What is the derivative of a matrix product with respect to one of the matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let $A \in R^{n \times d}$ and $B \in R^{d \times m}$, and let $ C = AB $.
How would $ \frac{dC}{dB} $ be defined?

Intuitively, I feel it's $ A^T $, but I'm a little unclear how to arrive at it mathematically.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What about $A(B' - B)$ vs $\frac{\mathrm dC}{\mathrm dB}(B' - B)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's define $f(B)=AB$. Then the directional derivative along a matrix $D$ is
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(B+hD)-f(B)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{A(B+hD)-AB}{h}=AD.
$$
This means that the [Gateaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) is given by $d_BfD=AD$ or simply $d_Bf=A$.